# Predict the output in Un-sysnchronized threads

Tags: operating-system

i is a global variable with value 5 and function v() is called in by three threads.

```
v()
{
    i++;
    i--;
}
```

**The threads are not synchronized.**
what is the no. of possible outcomes of i and what are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output will always be `i=5` because `i++` is a single statement (the same holds for `i--`) and whatever is the order of the statements `i++` and `i--`, the result is always `i=5`.

If you have `int tmp = i; i = tmp + 1;` instead of `i++`, you can have `i≠5` because `int tmp = i; i = tmp + 1;` is not a single statement.

Here are all possibilities with two threads (named A and B):

```
        | i = 5
A: i++  | i = 6
A: i--  | i = 5
B: i++  | i = 6
B: i--  | i = 5

        | i = 5
A: i++  | i = 6
B: i++  | i = 7
A: i--  | i = 6
B: i--  | i = 5

        | i = 5
A: i++  | i = 6
B: i++  | i = 7
B: i--  | i = 6
A: i--  | i = 5
```

Comment: What if the first thread after executiong i++ is preempted & second thread starts its execution?

Comment: I have added all possibilities to my answer (in the case of 2 threads but it is the same for 5 threads).

Comment: In case of three threads, i have calculated & its coming one out of 5,6,7,8 in all cases. Hope it's correct.

Comment: Why do you think `i++` is atomic? [Special code](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.32/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic_32.h#L86) suggests that it is not so.

Comment: Because the increment instruction is available on all the most common processors. I assume the compiler is smart enough to use it.

Comment: @Thomash: What about dirty caches? Thread A can write 6 to main memory, then B can capture the value of i to some cache and run to completion, then A can write 5 to main memory and finally B can flush its cache. Causing i to be 6. Is this case possible?